# What's math formula for coupling between attendees

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know max dancing partner count for 2 sequences, i.e.
if we know a girl Alice want to dance with Tom and Bob, we mark '1' in following grid, I want to know max possible pairs:

, with following grid, max pairs is 3, I just want to know if there are a math formula can get the max pair, if no such math formula, how to calculate it?

```
3 pairs: Joan vs. Bob, Avy vs Tom, Jessica vs.Mike
3 pairs: Alice vs Tom, Joan vs. Bob, Jessica vs. Mike
2 pairs: Alice vs Bob, Jessica vs. Tom    

.        Tom Bob Mike
Alice     1   1 
Joan          1
Jessica   1       1
Avy       1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is [maximum matching in a bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

There is not an explicit formula, but there are efficient algorithms to
find the solution. See the link above.

In Mathematica there was the function [MaximalBipartiteMatching](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/ref/MaximalBipartiteMatching.html) in the GraphUtilities package.

Since version 10.0 it has apparently been superseeded by the function [FindIndependentEdgeSet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html).